# Setting text of button from an action listener

Tags: java, swing

So I have a `JComboBox` and two `JButton` controls in my code.

```
String[] s1 = { "NL", "EN"}; 

c1 = new JComboBox<>(s1);  
c1.setBounds(10, 10, 50, 20);
desgin.startFrame.add(c1); 

JButton button = desgin.makeButton(desgin.startFrame, 100, 100, 180, 50, json.getLanguage(languageMenu())[3]);
JButton jButton = desgin.makeButton(desgin.startFrame, 100, 180, 180, 50, json.getLanguage(languageMenu())[4]);
```

The language on the buttons should change the moment I change the language in the combo box, but I have no idea how to do that. I have tried using async:

```
c1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                JButton button = desgin.makeButton(desgin.startFrame, 100, 100, 180, 50, json.getLanguage(languageMenu())[3]);
                JButton jButton = desgin.makeButton(desgin.startFrame, 100, 180, 180, 50, json.getLanguage(languageMenu())[4]);
                    return null;
                }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                System.out.println("Done");
            }

        }.execute();    
    }
});
```

But it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setText(java.lang.String)

Comment: *"Problems with java swing"* Is a poor title. The Java & Swing parts are redundant because those tags are added. 'problems' is so vague as to be of no use narrowing down what the problem is, and arguably *every* question on SO is because of a 'problem'. Better a descriptive title like 'Setting text of button from an action listener'. I.E. **Descriptive!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just use `'setText()'` method of `JButton` , inside of the actionListener. You should not create new button everytime.